# Tree component in react native

Tags: react-native

I did some search to find a tree component in react native.
But I can't seem to find one.
Is there no react native tree component?
What to do if one needs a tree component?

Comment: you'll need to provide more informations if you wanna be helped. What is a tree component to you ?

Comment: @LouisLecocq e.g. this https://github.com/fritz-c/react-sortable-tree

Answer (score 1):

you can use this library

[react-native-final-tree-view](https://github.com/zaguiini/react-native-final-tree-view)

[image]

and here you can find a good example for it :
[React Native Tree View for Android and IOS devices](https://aboutreact.com/react-native-final-tree-view/)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** This library is not any more maintained.

React native have no tree component. But there are some npm packages are available for tree component.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-treeview

Comment: Did you find any success with this library? I have tried it but did not found any success. :(
https://aboutreact.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Screenshot_1556737444.png